# Versions of the verb 'lehnen'

Tags: translation, verb, german-to-english, prefix

Could you please explain the meanings of:

- lehnen
- anlehnen
- auflehnen
- ablehnen

Comment: Isn't it in your dictionary? Here's e.g. leo on *auflehnen*: http://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/auflehnen. In general, prefixes don't have a fixed meaning but create separate verbs and you have to learn all the meanings for each verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hier sind ein paar Beispiele für die Verwendung von 'lehnen', 'anlehnen', 'ablehnen', 'auflehnen'. Und als Bonuswort: 'hinauslehnen'.

> Paul **lehnte** die Leiter an den Baum, stieg hinauf und pflückte einen Apfel für seine Geliebte.
>
> "Oh, danke!" sagte die Geliebte. "Darf ich mich bei dir **anlehnen**?"
>
> Daraufhin Paul: "Dieses Angebot muss ich leider **ablehnen**."
>
> Nach einiger Zeit fuhr er fort: "An meine vorigen Worte **anlehnend** möchte ich noch anmerken, dass du dich auch nicht so stark gegen die Wand **lehnen** solltest, die ist nicht so stabil, am Ende fällt sie um!"
>
> Die Geliebte: "Das wäre in der Tat **abzulehnen**!"
>
> Und Paul fuhr fort: "Du solltest dich auch nicht so stark zum Fenster **hinauslehnen**! Du könntest hinunterfallen!"
>
> Da antwortete die Geliebte schnippisch: "Wenn du alles, was ich tue, doch nur **ablehnst**, dann werde ich mich gegen dich **auflehnen**." Sprach's, packte ihren Apfel und stapfte entrüstet vondannen.

Comment: Danke! Die Beispiele haben mir sehr geholfen.